# How to move to end of a file upon opening it via a command in .vimrc using vim/MacVim?

Tags: vim, macvim

I'm trying to open a file using a command I set in my .vimrc file. The relevant line in my .vimrc is similar to the following:

```
command Of so /Users/Dude/Working/open_file.txt
```

With open_file.txt containing the following:

```
tabnew /Users/Dude/Working/Project/config.txt
```

What I'd like to do when executing the 'Of' command is navigate to the end of config.txt. I've tried adding a large line number which is unlikely to exceed the number of lines in the file like so:

```
tabnew /Users/Dude/Working/Project/config.txt
250000
```

This takes me to the end of the file but doesn't seem like the right way to do it. Ideally, I'd also like to add a new line after the last line and navigate there too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at `:h :normal` in your case just write `:norm Go` instead of your number there.

Comment: @romainl thanks for the edit (nobody has to see the embrassing errors there '^^). But a question about the `norm Go` vs `:norm Go` edit. I know both of them work in a sourced file and since you explicitly edited it to `:norm Go` I would like to ask if it is bad style to just write `norm Go` in a sourced file or what other reason there is for the edit (this part of the edit, the rest ist perfectly fine!)

Answer (score 3):

A few things:

1. I would suggest you use full names instead of short names. e.g. `so` -> `source`.
2. `source` is probably the wrong choice here as you can do everything with the right-hand-side of `command`
3. May want to use `!` with `command` so you can resource your `vimrc` file. e.g. `command! Of ...`
4. `$` represents the last line of the file. No need to choose a magic number
5. Create a new line can be done with `:normal o` or `:put _`

So with some tweaks we get the following command:

```
command! Of tabedit /Users/Dude/Working/Project/config.txt | $put_
```

For more help see:

```
:h :command
:h :put
:h :range
:h :bar
```

Answer (score 0):

`:tabnew`, like most variants of `:edit` (and the command-line arguments when launching Vim), takes arbitrary Ex commands via the `[+cmd]` argument. The `$` command will move to the end of the file:

```
tabnew +$ /Users/Dude/Working/Project/config.txt
```